# return selected properties with Joined complete entity

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hql

i need to return custom response, so i tried below query

```
 @Query("SELECT g.name as name,g.id as id, city as city, g.listOfEquipment as listOfEquipment,g.listOfSlot as listOfSlot" +
            " FROM Gym g INNER JOIN g.city as city " +
            "WHERE city.id=:cityId")
    List<Map<String, Object>> listing(@Param("cityId") Integer cityId, Pageable pageable);
```

as you can see my intention is to return `city` and `listOfEquipment` and `listOfSlot` also.

i was thinking this will works but unfortunately its not working
i am getting `PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."`

please help me for the right approach

Comment: What does that part mean ?  : `FROM Gym g INNER JOIN g.city as city`

Comment: @Berger need for selected city only so `FROM Gym g INNER JOIN g.city as city WHERE city.id=:cityId`

Answer (score 1):

Try to join like below.

```
FROM Gym g INNER JOIN  city
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Query("SELECT g.name as name,g.id as id, g.city as city, g.listOfEquipment as 
listOfEquipment, g.listOfSlot as listOfSlot" +
        " FROM Gym g " +
        "WHERE g.city.id=:cityId")
```

Your `city` property is inside Gym so, you can directly reach.